# How to appropriately implement infinite while loops in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm creating a program that allows the user to `login`, `create`, or `restore` their account using the keys `1`, `2`, and `3`.

The `mainf` module asks the user to select an option, which then then calls a function from a different module.

`mainf` module:

```
import createnewaccount
import loginf
import restoreaccount


def main():
    options = {
        "LOGIN": 1,
        "CREATE NEW ACCOUNT": 2,
        "RESTORE ACCOUNT": 3,
    }

    print("------------------------")
    for options, choices in options.items():
        print(options + ' - ' + str(choices))
    print("------------------------")

    while True:
        try:
            user_option = (input("Select an option 1-3: \n"))
            user_option = int(user_option)
            if user_option < 1 or user_option > 3:
                raise Exception
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid response.")
        except Exception:
            print("Invalid option.")
        else:
            return user_option


user_ = main()

if user_ == 1:
    loginf.login_information()
if user_ == 2:
    createnewaccount.main()
if user_ == 3:
    restoreaccount.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```

In order to debug my code, I've deleted everything in my `loginf` module, and allowed it to only `return "Hello"`.

`loginf` module:

```
def login_information():
    return print("Hello")
```

The user should receive `"Hello"` every time they've selected the key `1`.
However, this is my output instead:

```
C:\Users\raamis\PycharmProjects\test\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/raamis/PycharmProjects/test/mainf.py
------------------------
LOGIN - 1
CREATE NEW ACCOUNT - 2
RESTORE ACCOUNT - 3
------------------------
Select an option 1-3: 
1
Hello
------------------------
LOGIN - 1
CREATE NEW ACCOUNT - 2
RESTORE ACCOUNT - 3
------------------------
Select an option 1-3: 
1
------------------------
LOGIN - 1
CREATE NEW ACCOUNT - 2
RESTORE ACCOUNT - 3
------------------------
Select an option 1-3:
```

Comment: I think your chosen question title doesn't quite grasp the problem you are grappling with hear. "How to appropriately implement infinite while loops in Python?", well, simply `while True:`

Comment: There is a mistake in the second loop. You are looping through `main()`, but only for the first time you are calling `loginf.login_information()`. So, there is always a `1` return, but only once a `Hello`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your module through command line, these instructions are executed first:

```
user_ = main()

if user_ == 1:
    loginf.login_information()
if user_ == 2:
    createnewaccount.main()
if user_ == 3:
    restoreaccount.main()
```

which explains that "Hello" is printed (as expected) the first time.

Then, the following instructions are executed:

```
while True:
    main()
```

which explains that "Hello" is NOT printed the next times, because `loginf.login_information()` is not called here.

I suggest you the following fix:

```
import createnewaccount
import loginf
import restoreaccount


def get_option():
    options = {
        "LOGIN": 1,
        "CREATE NEW ACCOUNT": 2,
        "RESTORE ACCOUNT": 3,
    }

    print("------------------------")
    for options, choices in options.items():
        print(options + ' - ' + str(choices))
    print("------------------------")

    while True:
        try:
            user_option = (input("Select an option 1-3: \n"))
            user_option = int(user_option)
            if user_option < 1 or user_option > 3:
                raise Exception
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid response.")
        except Exception:
            print("Invalid option.")
        else:
            return user_option

def main():
    user_ = get_option()

    if user_ == 1:
        loginf.login_information()
    if user_ == 2:
        createnewaccount.main()
    if user_ == 3:
        restoreaccount.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because "if conditions" not in an infinite loop, they are just executed once when the file executed.

You can achieve your expected result by putting if conditions in infinite while loop like given below -

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        user_ = main()

        if user_ == 1:
            loginf.login_information()
            print("inside ")
        if user_ == 2:
            createnewaccount.main()
        if user_ == 3:
            restoreaccount.main()
```